# Wi-Fi works well in other devices but shows "limited connectivity" in my Sony Xperia Mini Pro

Tags: wi-fi

I have a BSNL router in my house. I can connect and browse using Wi-Fi in my laptop and my brother's and dad's mobile but it shows limited connectivity in my Sony Xperia Mini Pro.

It has WEP security. I've used that Wi-Fi earlier but now it shows as limited connectivity to mine alone. Even if I enter the wrong password, it shows "obtaining IP address" and shows "limited connectivity". I've also  used static IP address option in that. It gets connected in that case but I can't browse.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Mybe You have a firewall app that it limited your internet access
Check it

Answer (score -1):

use dynamic ip address ..and forget network and restart  your mobile  and then enter correct password in wifi network .and  stay in wifi router range.